# python os.walk glob very cpu intensive

Tags: python, windows, cpu, glob, os.walk

I need to traverse through windows directories and get each ad every file name.I tried os.walk and glob (Python 2.7). Both are really cpu intensive. CPU usage immediately shoots to 100% and clogs my system.

I am using the standard for loop to recursive go through the directories.

```
for path, folders, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
    for file_name in files:
        print file_name
```

or

```
print glob('C:\\*\*\*')
```

What am i missing here? Does normal directory traversal takes so much resource? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: use `profiler` to see where the actual time is spent up

Comment: Printing to a terminal will also cause a bit of a spike, so it might be worth just storing the results in a variable and profiling that

Comment: @NishantSingh 674085 function calls (632384 primitive calls) in 25.243 seconds

Comment: @SimonFraser instead of printing it on the terminal, appended it into a list. 724776 function calls in 6.66 seconds.

Comment: @SimonFraser even with this shorter time, when i process the list the cpu usage still jumps to 100%

Comment: Python's built-in `os.walk()` is significantly slower than it needs to be, because -- in addition to calling `os.listdir()` on each directory -- it executes the `stat()` system call or `GetFileAttributes()` on each file to determine whether the entry is a directory or not.
Can you try `os.scandir()` and show what u got

Comment: @NishantSingh  446496 function calls (404218 primitive calls) in 13.788 seconds with cpu usage still 100%

Comment: Python 3.5 has an update to os.walk that now uses os.scandir underneath and is supposedly 7-20 times faster on Windows - https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-471-os-scandir-function-a-better-and-faster-directory-iterator

Comment: python 3.5 os.scandir() recursive directory traversal gives me permission denied error. Where did that come from?